# C# Using TcpListener on both Client and Server

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32633/Sending-Files-using-TCP) to setup a client -> server TCP based windows forms application where the **server receives a file from the client** and it works well. The summary of the structure would be:

> Server uses **TcpListener** to listen
>
> Client uses **TcpClient** to send

Now I am trying to do the opposite by **sending a file from the server to client**, using the same method. I tried the following structure:

> Server uses **TcpClient** to send
>
> Client uses **TcpListener** to listen

However I get the following **error**:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Is this because the client and the server is listening to the same port as described by the error? How else can I send and receive files both ways?

My code is the exact code posted in that thread I linked, therefore I didn't post it here. Let me know if I should post my code here as well :)

Comment: Usually it's not a good idea to use TcpListener on client, because it might be hard to read client from server (firewall, NAT and so on). What exactly you are trying to do? Maybe client can first request that file, and then server will send it in response?

Comment: I am trying to send a file from server to client @Evk I have already made the functionality to send a file from client to server. I need to do the opposite as well so that it's a two way communication

Comment: I mean client might first request that file (send something to server which means "give me file X") and server will send that file in response (over the same channel). Tcp is already two-way communication, so you don't need separate channels for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, what you are trying to do is not a very good idea, but to answer your question:

The error is pretty self-explanatory.  You are trying to use a port number which is already in use.  So, just use a different port number.  (The `PortN` parameter in the tutorial.)  In other words, have one pair of TcpListener and TcpClient communicate via port X, and the other (reverse) pair communicate via port X+1.